# Length of shared data exceeds shared segment size- getting this error in perl code

Tags: perl

I am getting the error- "Length of shared data exceeds shared segment size" in my perl code when I am trying to read a csv file and load its contents into a shared variable.
I am using the below code-

```
use IPC::Shareable;
my %options = (
    create    => 1,
    exclusive => 0,
    mode      => 0666,
    destroy   => 1,
);
my $handle = tie $arr_share, 'IPC::Shareable', $glue, { %options } or
    die "server: tie failed\n";
```

The CSV file is over 20 mega bytes. I have also tried defining size = 'some value', but it didnt work. Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: You are running into OS limits. You need to either: reduce the size of your data; spread the data over multiple variables (each var is stored in one OS shared memory segment) or configure your OS to increase the maximum shared memory segment size - how you do this depends on your OS

Comment: I tried reading the CSV file in chunks and storing each chunk of data into separate variables. But some how I am not able to fetch the chunk of data in variables. Could you please suggest me on this. Thanks

Comment: I tried as below-
my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new ({ binary => 1, auto_diag => 1 });
  open my $fh, "<:encoding(utf8)", "$uas_file" or die "uas_file: $!";
  while (my $row = $csv->getline ($fh)) {
   $line_counter++;
    if ($line_counter > $size) {
    push @{$outvar} ,'$output'.$file_counter;
    @{$outvar}[$file_counter]= $ranges;
    undef $ranges;
    $size+=100;
    $file_counter++;
   }
    my $ipmin = $row->[4]; 
    my $ipmax = $row->[5];
    my $range = {
     ipmin => $ipmin,
     ipmax => $ipmax
    };
    push @{$ranges}, $range;
    
  }

Comment: @Dumb: Please don't put code in comments - it's (as you can see) unreadable. Instead, please update your question and add the code there.

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates that your data structure is too large for the provided `size` option.

When modified, the entire data structure is serialized using [Storable](https://metacpan.org/pod/Storable). This serialization must fit in the shared memory block whose size is controlled by the `size` option. (The default size is 1 KiB.) A 20 MiB CSV could easily require 500 MiB of shared memory.

Which begs the question... Does it make sense for your code to create a 500 MiB string every time a change is made? How about parsing a 500 MiB string every time data is fetched?  This might not be the best approach for you.

Comment: What should be the best approach to do so. Please suggest

Comment: Depends on the problem